# JS Graph library supporting labeled edges

Tags: javascript, graph

I'm looking for a graph (not chart) library for javascript. I only need to draw less than 10 nodes, so performance is not a big issue.

Needed features:

- should be able to coexist with / use jQuery
- directed graphs
- align graph automatically (no collisions is sufficient I think)
- ability to label edges
- ideally it's free as *free beer* and *freedom of speech*

I found a good [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript) with many libs. But none of them seemed to support labels for edges.

Any hints?

Comment: I don't really care in what way it gets rendered. If I can easily create an svg with some lib, then that's a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://js.cytoscape.org/)?

I haven't used it, but the demo looks like it supports your main points.

Comment: This one really seems to support everything I need. The only thing that bugs me a little is, that it uses flash. But since there doesn't seem to be an alternative I'll go with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think that arbor.js can do the work > http://arborjs.org/.

It is based on jQuery, aligns graph automatically and makes directed graphs. You can also label edges. Look at this post:

> [Add label to edges in arbor.js (Query plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499047/add-label-to-edges-in-arbor-js-query-plugin)

One example of labeled edges:

> http://arborjs.org/halfviz/#/the-abominable-snowman

Hope this could help you!

Comment: arborjs only has this wobbly layouting and labels (as well as nodes) would have to be drawn manually...so there's no real help for me in this lib...but thanks anyway

Comment: Currently arbor seems to be unmaintained with many issues remaining unfixed. A shame, since it's a nice and cleanly documented little library. In my (brief) experience it'll do the job if all you need is something similar to its demos. I like that it lets you do your own drawing.

Answer (score 2):

[JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html) for Javascript supports your required features, *but I'm afraid it isn't free*.

In their words:

> mxGraph is the only fully client-side JavaScript Graph Visualization
>   and Layout Solution

It also has a good StackExchange-based [forum](http://forum.jgraph.com/) for support.

Comment: At least $4.900...That is a little too expensive for my project. But from what I saw this is a really full featured library.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three open source options that all support laying out directed graphs. Some have tools to render them too:

1. [JointJS](http://jointjs.com/) is a great free library, and has several [demos](http://jointjs.com/demos/fsa) with source which are worth a look. Its UI can be used to edit and manually modify the layout of the graphs as well.
2. [Springy](http://getspringy.com/) is a library for laying out and rendering directed graphs using a spring/force model.
3. [Dagre](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre) is a layout engine for directed graphs that runs purely client-side and is rendering agnostic.

This [blog post](http://www.daviddurman.com/automatic-graph-layout-with-jointjs-and-dagre.html) described using JointJS and Dagre in tandem.

Answer (score 0):

Canviz (http://code.google.com/p/canviz/) does support edge labeling.

For example, see `dfa.gv` at http://www.ryandesign.com/canviz/.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can see this needs preprocessing on the server side (generating an [xdot file](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html#d:xdot) which needs graphviz). So this is not really only client JS. I need to create graphs dynamically and generating xdots without graphviz seems to be pretty difficult. Plus it's not sure if this will run with jQuery (see [#66](http://code.google.com/p/canviz/issues/detail?id=66&q=jquery&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary))